Four finger tap on Debian 12 LXDE
On my new built Debian 12 machine running LXDE, I found by accident that a 4 finger tap on my touchpad will cause an immediate screen off (same as if I'd done xset dpms force off).
I think a 3 finger tap does a paste, but I'm not sure.
How can I find what all these obscure gestures do, and how I can configure LXDE (openbox) to do more "interesting" things?
